Why ADL does not kick in with unqualified swap() and std::size_t
Why wouldn't ADL kick in when I use unqualified swap() function with std::size_t passed arguments type? For example, I'd expect this to work:
std::size_t v1, v2;
swap(v1, v2);

But it does not. On my compiler, I see the std::size_t is indeed inside std:: namespace.
This works as expected:
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
swap(v1, v2);

What am I missing?

ADL doesn't consider namespaces of the typedefs, only those of the actual type. std::size_t is a typedef for some built-in integral type, and thus doesn't have an associated namespace. In other words, the type of v1 is say unsigned long long, not any type from std namespace. The fact that you happened to use a typedef to declare the variable doesn't change its type, and doesn't associate additional namespaces with it.

Argument-dependent lookup: 1) For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty.

Thanks folks. I had the feeling that this was the direction! thanks!!
